# Convert ARC code to non-ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm struggling to get an existing ARC-enabled control to run under Xcode 4.2 (OSX Snow Leopard), in a non-ARC-enabled project, and I'm facing various issues :

How should I fix the following issues ?

- Use of `(strong)` in properties
- Use of `(nonatomic)` in properties
- Instance methods not found (not having being declared in the interface)
- Enable new-style Objective-C

Also, it seems to be complaining about `NSScrollerKnobStyle` not being defined. Is it a 10.8-to-10.6 SDK-specific issue?

---

P.S. The control I'm using is [ITSidebar](https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITSidebar)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to change those `strong` properties to `retain` or `copy`, as appropriate. There's nothing wrong with `nonatomic` in non-ARC code.

You may have to add `@synthesize` directives for your properties to get the compiler to add accessor methods. `@synthesize` is the default in the latest compiler.

There ae a number of other changes to the language, such as object literals. They're all well documented; you just need to apply them in reverse.

I'm not sure about `NSScrollerKnobStyle`, but if you look it up the documentation will tell you when it was introduced.